# Creating a Search function in Xamarin.android to query Microsoft Azure table records

Tags: c#, android, sql, azure, xamarin

In Xamarin, I create an EditText Field and a Search Button, when a user taps the button on their Android device, it must search the Azure database tables, find the relevant record and display/populate it in the record_view.axml I created?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Id_row"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Name_row"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Mobile_row"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Email_row"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have the same rows above in the Azure database as columns.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, a tutorial or some info regarding this will really help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/azure/mobile-services/) and [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/).

Here is a small example, showing how you can use `Where()` to filter your tables:

```
public async Task<List<Person>> Search()
{
    // you'd access your xml here
    TextView nameTextView = null;

    // using real keys
    MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(AppUrl, AppKey);

    // and real data objects
    IMobileServiceTable<Person> personTable = client.GetTable<Person> ();

    // just to keep things clean, an interstitial var
    string name = nameTextView.Text;

    // use LINQ to filter on the properties we care about
    // you can add && p.Blah == whatever, as much as you'd like
    return await personTable.Where (p => p.Name == name).ToListAsync();
}
```

Additionally, Azure lets you define custom [APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn303368.aspx), one of which may make your searching easier, if you'd like to make it fuzzy, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Josh, can I use the 'where' function with an 'if' statement. When the user types in a search field and clicks search? I'm not too sure why I'm finding this so difficult,however I am new to Xamarin and Azure, I usually figure it out after testing a bit, not this time though.

Comment: Not working correctly. public async List<PrecinctData> Search() gives error - The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>

Comment: Also getting error on these lines,  MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(AppUrl, AppKey); (the type 'system.net.http.httpmessagehandler' is definedin an assembly that is not referenced, you must add a reference to the assembly. Also on last line it says cannot implictly convert type system.collections.generic.list <appname.personData> to appname.personData.

Comment: Yeah, I just quickly banged that out. you'll want to return `Task<List<PrecinctData>>`, as it is awaitable. And there is an error on the new Client line because it's being instantiated with 2 random variables I made up, `AppUrl` and `AppKey`. You'll want to replace that with your actual url / key from Azure. And probably not make the client in the method anyway, this was merely meant to illustrate that you can `.Where()` on a table.